# how to use this flex compiler option copy non embeded files to destination folder

Tags: apache-flex, ant

i am using mxmlc for building the flex projects using ant.how to use flex builder-> copy non embeded files to destination folder compiler option in ANT

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you out but when you check that option using flex builder it updates the .actionScriptProperties file:

```
<compiler additionalCompilerArguments="-locale en_US" copyDependentFiles="true">
<compilerSourcePath/>
</compiler>
```

setting the copyDependentFiles to true or false turns this on and off

You can all just copy the directory over but this doesn't remove the embedded files.

```
<copy todir="${SRC_DIR}/assets">
<fileset dir="${DEPLOY_DIR}">
</fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: i am not expecting this.i am asking how to use this copydependentfiles=true option in ant script